# Not suspending activities Android

Tags: android, game-engine, lifecycle

I'm developing a video game for Android and I have a couple of doubts:

1) How can I make that the mobile doesn't suspend while I have the game running?

2) If I minimize my game and then open another, if I come back again to my game, the game restarts. I think Android destroys it because is not being used. What can I do to avoid this? I don't want that my game restarts if I open another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use a WAKE_LOCK. Look at the permission android.permission.WAKE_LOCK

2) This time, look at the Android [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). That can be a memory leak too, there is some tools to track that. You can find a tutorial on the [Android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). 
If there is no memory leak may be you use the "savedinstancestate" to run your game when you have paused. One more time, I recommand [that tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) from the documentation that explain how to save your activity state and recreate it.

edit : More information about wakelock :

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

And mainly **do not forget** to release your wakelock

```
wl.release();
```

Comment: You're welcome. I have add some details about wakelock.